# Can I get a faculty job in the UK without UK experience?

Tags: united-states, faculty-application, united-kingdom

I have worked as an Assistant Professor in Japan for 5 years and can apply for promotion, but for personal reasons, I cannot live in Japan. I plan to apply for a Senior Lecturer/Reader position in the UK.

A friend of mine who works in the UK told me **you cannot get a teaching position in the UK unless you have studied or worked in the UK higher education.**

She suggested that I have a better chance to get a job in the US where universities do not expect a local experience if the application is strong at the international standard.

Comment: This is not true, I can give you countless counterexamples from my narrow fields. Many people becomes lecturer (i.e. assistant professor) after PhD/postdoc in Japan/Korea.

Comment: Could you clarify whether your friend meant "cannot" in the practical or theoretical sense?

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure what type of answer you are looking for. Based on personal experience as an American with all my education and training in the US, my first faculty position was as a lecturer in the UK. There are no laws requiring UK experience to get a faculty position of any rank in the UK. There are laws that give preference to those who have a right to work in the UK, but that is not the same as UK based teaching/education experience.

While some schools may prefer individuals with UK based experience, it was never something that came up during our searches. That said a familiarity with the UK system is helpful for demonstrating you can be a good tutor and help advise students.

Comment: The US and UK systems are similar. I think the point mentioned in the question is that UK universities do not trust someone who has successfully worked in Japan (I personally have no idea how is the education system there) can meet the teaching standards and norms in the UK.

Comment: @All apart from being taught in English, I wouldn't describe the US and UK systems as being similar. That said, if the question is really *is Japanese experience valuable when applying for a UK job*, the OP should edit the question.

Comment: Then, as an American working in the UK, you have perfectly answered the question: `your chance is the same in the UK and the US.`

Comment: @All and we hired people from Australia, Germany, France, Netherlands, Canada with no experience with the UK system. I don't recall ever seeing an applicant from Japan, but I don't think it would have mattered.

Comment: Definitely hiring from EU countries is much easier than from North America, because EU has a harmonized education system with lots of exchange programs such as Erasmus. As you mentioned, some universities prefer not to sponsor for the work permit. In this case, I think Australians and New Zealanders can get the work permit easier.

Comment: In addition, EU law requires third country applications only to be taken when there is no suitable EU candidate (of course there are many ways this can be gamed if desired - in particular with very narrow or tailored job descriptions).